# why not use command 'CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector' directly?

Tags: c, makefile

```
CFLAGS  := -fno-builtin -Wall -g -m32 -mno-sse -nostdinc $(DEFS)
CFLAGS  += $(shell $(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo -fno-stack-protector)
```

In the second line,i confuse  why not use command `CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector` directly?

Comment: Strange idiom. That sort of test is better suited for a configure script than directly in a makefile to be run every time you compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to do a build-time check that the C compiler supports the `-fno-stack-protector` flag.

If the compiler doesn't support the flag then `$(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` will fail and nothing will be added to `CFLAGS`.

These kinds of checks are usually done by a build configuration script.

Comment: I have another question, if  `$(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` fail,the `make` will abort  or continue ?

Comment: @kapike It's run in an independent sub-shell (that's what the `$(shell)` function does) that is not connected to the `make` process, so `make` will continue. Otherwise that test would be pretty useless.